# mySQL getting a list of unique values within a group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table 'results':

```
(name,score,state)  
joe small, 10, NC  
joe small, 5, MN
jane doe, 9, AL
```

I have this query:

`SELECT name, avg(score)

FROM results
group by name`

I would like to add a new result column of unique states (alphabetical order) related to name to each row of output like so:

```
joe small, 5, CA MN NV  
jane doe, 7, AL CA FL
```

Would I do this with a nested select statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT name, 
    avg(score), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(state SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM results 
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: +1, but you'll need to use  `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTNCT  state....)` if you want *unique states*